# MongoDB Aggregegation: Distinct on other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

**employees**

- _id
- office
- jobTitle

**offices**

- _id
- city

I am trying to receive a list of all office locations with the job titles of employees of the respecitve office.

The end result would look like this:

```
[{
 _id: ObjectId('6086f617cc0824cc4ce7c9f0'),
 city: "Berlin",
 jobTitles: ['SOFTWARE ENGINEER', 'CEO', 'CFO']
}, {
 _id: ObjectId('60c08d36f925f3083488ea79'),
 city: "Prague",
 jobTitles: ['UX DESIGNER', 'BUSINESS ANALYST']
}]
```

This is the aggregation I've tried, with no success:

```
db.offices.aggregate([{
 $lookup: {
  from: 'employees',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'office',
  as: 'jobTitles',
  project: [{
    $group: { _id: '$jobTitle'}
  }]
 }
}]);
```

One office can have thousands of employees, so I'm trying to make the query as efficient as possible.

Thank you for your ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

use `$lookup`

```
db.offices.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "employees",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "office",
      "as": "jobTitles"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "jobTitles": "$jobTitles.jobTitles"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$jobTitles"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "city": {
        "$first": "$city"
      },
      jobTitles: {
        $addToSet: "$jobTitles"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QynvUMdos7S)

Comment: Wow thats quite simple! Thanks! But how am I able to avoid duplicate items in jobTitles?

Comment: I update my answer to avoid duplicate items by using `$unwind` and `$group`